# no valid keychain for xcode

Tags: xcode

after 6 month of break I try to finish my first app.
After I downloaded the new XCode and the new SDK (I needed it, because old XCode and SDK was 4.3, my iPhone was on 5.0.1) I try to build, but it told me my signiture was to old.
So I cleared all things I have found in my keychain: certificates, keys and so on.

I remember that it is a really really mess, but I tried the last 5 hours withour writing a single line of code...

At the moment I created a new certificate in the Apple Online Portal.
I downloaded and double click it, so it's in the Organizer now.

The error from XCode when try to start on my device is now:
There are no valid certificate/private key pairs in the default keychain

Can someone help me? (Skype would be nice), I am really lost in this after 5 ours of triend all I found on google and get very very lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are installing certificates first time you will have to install  `"Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority"`.

Check whether it is available in the `system tab` of keychain access.
If you double click the certificate and provide password, it may be possible that it gets added to `system tab`. So make sure it is added to the `login tab`.You can just drag and drop the certificate from system to login.
In xcode organiser window you should see the provisioning profiles. If you don't see your profile there install the profile double clicking it. Also check profiles' expiry date.!
Hope this Helps!

Comment: Didnt help. I allreay have this certificate, but I didn't have any private / public key